# Svelte ancor no funciona en en mobile

Tags: programación-móvil

Buenas como andan? tengo un proyecto en Svelte que tiene hipervinculos ancor a secciones d ela misma web SPA

el tema es que en descktop funcionan los vinculos peor en mobile no apsa nada... no se si es algo que falta de ruteo (com oen otros frameworcks) o que sucede...

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.